# System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin.android

I'm creating an android application with Xamarin in visual studio and I end up getting the error:

> "System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2):
>   ReceiveFailure".

This happens after the service I created tries to return a list but ends up stopping at my CompletedEventArgs result call. My Android app has a proxy client which calls my WCF service which communicates with SQL Server. My code follows as such:

```
private void ClientOnGetTransactionsCompleted(object sender, GetTransactionsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        transactions = new List<TransactionInterface>();
        try
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Result.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Result.Length; i++)
            {
                transactions.Add((TransactionInterface)e.Result[i]);
            }
            RunOnUiThread(() => list.Adapter = new AccountAdapter(this, transactions));
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to populate a list with two different objects that are part of TransactionInterface. I can populate the list just fine from within my activity but when I call the service it fails. My service code is this:

```
public List<TransactionInterface> GetTransactions(string id)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        var tollQuery = from t in context.Tolls
                        where t.account_id.Equals(id)
                        select new InterfaceTollTest(t.status_time, t.fee, t.plate_id); 
        var paymentQuery = from p in context.Payments
                           where p.account_id.Equals(id)
                           select new InterfacePaymentTest(p.status_time, p.payment1, p.credit_type);
        var tolls = tollQuery.ToList();
        var payments = paymentQuery.ToList();
        var all = new List<TransactionInterface>();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Bunny Rabbit");
        for (int i = 0; i < tolls.Count; i++)
        {
            all.Add(tolls[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < payments.Count; i++)
        {
            all.Add(tolls[i]);
        }

        return all;
    }
```

I've tested my code to check if my query is working properly and it is returning everything as expected. Maybe I'm casting it incorrectly in the service but I tried the same thing in the Activity to populate the list and it worked fine. The CompletedEventArgs returns object[] and I modified it to return List too but that didn't help. I tried both of these to see if I even get a result and it just stopped with the same error.

```
Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Length);
Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Count);
```

I'm not sure if I'm just overlooking some small mistake but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is wrong. The issue here is that my GetTransactions service is not supported in the WCF Test Client because it uses type System.Object[]. Since I was using SLsvcUtil to create my proxy client, it didn't show the [following screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anyEC.png) where the error was located. In order to get this to work created a DataContract in my service for the object I wanted to add to my List. Hope this helps anyone else with this issue.